# Prove that for all $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$, $a·b=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Prove that for all $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$, $a·b=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$.
>
> Using these field axioms:
>
> - (A1) Addition is commutative
> - (A2) Addition is associative
> - (A3) Addition has a neutral element $0$
> - (A4) Any element has an additive inverse
> - (A5) Multiplication is commutative
> - (A6) Multiplication is associative
> - (A7) Multiplication has a neutral element $1$
> - (A8) Any non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse
> - (A9) Multiplication distributes over addition

My answer: Suppose $=0$ and by (A6) $=1⋅=(^{−1}⋅)⋅=^{−1}⋅(⋅)$. Either $=0$ or it is not. If a does not equal $0$,then by (A8),there is a unique element $^{−1}=(1/)∈ℝ$ such that $^{−1}⋅(⋅)=^{−1}⋅0=0$ thus $b=0$

Comment: How from $a \cdot a^{-1}=1$ you conclude that $b=0$ ?

Comment: Because ab=0 so if a = 1, then b must be 0. Should I include that? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: You have to use : $a^{-1} \cdot (a \cdot b) = a^{-1} \cdot 0=0$.

Comment: So would this be efficient to say then? Suppose =0. Either =0 or it is not. If a does not equal 0,then by (A8),there is a unique element ^−1=(1/)∈ℝ such that ^−1⋅(⋅)=^−1⋅0=0 thus ab=0?

Comment: @brucemcmc If you add $b = 1\cdot b = (a^{-1}\cdot a)\cdot b = a^{-1}\cdot (a\cdot b)$ to the start of that sequnce of equalities, you're good to go, because that gives you $b = 0$ if you compare the leftmost end to the rightmost end.

Comment: @Arthur Suppose =0 and =1⋅=(^−1⋅)⋅=^−1⋅(⋅). Either =0 or it is not. If a does not equal 0,then by (A8),there is a unique element ^−1=(1/)∈ℝ such that ^−1⋅(⋅)=^−1⋅0=0 thus ab=0?

Comment: Why are you concluding with "thus $ab = 0$? That's unnecessary. We already assumed that, and it's not what we're after. And don't use $a^{-1}$ until you have assumed that $a\neq 0$.

Comment: @Arthur didn't I assume that a=0 or it is not? And should it then conclude as... thus a or b = 0? Sorry I am lost with my proof now :(

Comment: @brucemcmc I suggest you write your entire proof, as you have it right now, from start to finish, in your question post. I think that's easier than trying to fit bits and pieces of it in comments.

Comment: @Arthur I just did. By the way, thank you for all your help thus far.

Comment: @Arthur thank you for the help again. I was wondering, what literature do you recommend to enhance my abilities in proof writing/math?

Comment: @brucemcmc Do not [repost the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3118281/29335) as you did: edit the old one.  Also, please take time to write more useful titles.  The original title of this question and the original duplicate are useful to nobody.

Comment: @rschwieb okay will do :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose neither $a$ nor $b$ is zero. Then, since $\mathbb R$ is a field, all nonzero elements are invertible, hence, $a^{-1},b^{-1}$ exist. Now $a^{-1}abb^{-1}=1=0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose $ab = 0$ and $=1⋅=(^{−1}⋅)⋅=^{−1}⋅(⋅)$.

Here you get into trouble because you haven't assumed $a\neq 0$. Thus $a^{-1}$ might not exist.

> Either =0 or it is not. If a does not equal $0$,then by (A8),there is a unique element $^{−1}=(1/)∈ℝ$

Now you have established that $a^{-1}$ is valid.

> such that $^{−1}⋅(⋅)=^{−1}⋅0=0$ thus $b=0$

and this is where I meant you should put the hting you put right at the start.

---

Finished proof, in the right order:

Either $a = 0$ or $a\neq 0$. If $a = 0$ we're done. If not, then by $A8$ there is an $a^{-1}$ such that $a\cdot a^{-1} = 1$. By $A5$, we also have $a^{-1}\cdot a = 1$.

Thus if $a\neq 0$, we get
$$
b \stackrel{A7}= 1\cdot b \stackrel{A8+A5}= (a^{-1}\cdot a)\cdot b \stackrel{A6}= a^{-1}\cdot(a\cdot b)\stackrel{Assumption}=a^{-1}\cdot 0 = 0
$$
showing that $b = 0$.